# Postgres 2 different FKs in both directions

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I've run into a situation where we have 2 tables that have 2 different foreign key relationships, one is 1-many, the other is 1-1, but they are in opposite directions.  I'm wondering if postgres has a way to validate that the combination of the FKs must match, probably easier to show in an example.

```
table product {
  id: PK
  name ...etc
  preferred_vendor_product: FK to vendor_product id
}

table vendor_product {
   id: PK
   product_id: FK to product (a product could have many vendor products)
   price...etc
}
```

Is there a way to enforce that when I add a preferred vendor product to product, that not only the vendor_product must exist, but it's value in product_id must match the product in question.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a third table `preferred_vendor_product` that just has a fkey pointing to `vendor_product`. That table presumably should have a primary key of `(vendor_id, product_id)`.